# How to restrict some files while uploading a folder using HTML file input?

Tags: javascript, html

While uploading a folder using HTML file input tag, I want to upload only all text files that are in that folder(Suppose folder is having some text files, database files, config files etc.). How can I do this?

Answer (score 2):

You can specify the `accept` attribute of the input file.

```
<input type="file" accept=".txt" />
```

For more resources.

[https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_accept.asp#:~:text=The%20accept%20attribute%20specifies%20a,be%20validated%20on%20the%20server](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_accept.asp#:%7E:text=The%20accept%20attribute%20specifies%20a,be%20validated%20on%20the%20server).

Answer (score 0):

To make only text files show up when you use the input use the accept attribute like this:

```
<input type="file" accept=".doc,.docx,application/msword,application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document" />
```

But to be sure you should validate the value from the input in Javascript as well to add an extra layer of security.

Comment: That's just a example of some of the most common text file types.

Answer (score 0):

You can add `accept` attribute to the `<input type="file">`.

This Attibute can only be used with `<input type="file">`

Attribute specifies the filter for what file types the user can select from the file input dialog box.

```
<input type="file" accept=".txt"/>
```

There are other values to this attributes :

`audio/*` - pick all sound files

`image/*` - pick all image files

`video/*` - pick all video files

You can specify the file extension like *.gif*, *.png*, *.doc* etc.

As for your expectation - It is impossible to filter out only *.txt* files from the dialog box. Browser just make sure if the user has picked appropriate file as per written in `accept` attribute.

Comment: Will it work while uploading folder?

Comment: It will just validate if the file type is matched. It will not filter out the .txt files in your PC.
But It will work sure for validation of file types.

Answer (score -1):

It would be to validate only .txt files on upload so that it only recognizes these with the attribute in the accept=".txt" tag
On this page you can find more information:
https://www.htmlquick.com/es/reference/tags/input-file.html

Comment: Can you write a code?